# Execute a callback(or some other to send a message) when my node application fails

Tags: node.js, error-handling, runtime-error

I put a node based service on aws and it fails from time to time especially because I keep changing the code. It is important that it comes to my attention when this happens is there anything withing node can handle this ? Maybe something on the linux level ?

Ideally, I can execute some code when this happens and msg myself on telegram (simple api to do so) where I have set up all other alerts related to the service.

Comment: You can monitor cloudwatch logs by creating log based metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application logs are available in the cloudwatch logs, you can create a logs metric and create an alarm based on that metric. For e.g if a particular phrase appear in the logs, the alarm will trigger and send you an email. Hope this helps

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs//CountOccurrencesExample.html